# Mysql and PHP connection alive

Tags: php, mysql, shell, database-connection

Is it possibile to have something like "keepalive" for php-mysql connection to avoid many and many connections to db?

I need to log some events to database, these events can be thrown very often from command line script, so I think could be better to keep a connection alive for some time instead of open a new connection for every event.

Please mind that I'm asking for a pure php script, ***not a web server script***, called by a shell command:

```
> php /var/scripts/log.php
```

Is is possibile with standard php?

Comment: assuming you're using PDO I believe the drivers default to keep alive anyway. (also called persistent connections)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP5.3 or later then based on [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) the connection is by default persistent and also provides cleanup.

Comment: But is this true also for shell scripts or only for apache php module?